# How to solve classification problem that we should cluster elements, with Multinomial classification from CS229?

Tags: classification, clustering, multiclass-classification

I just learned about Multinomial classification ([CS229 Lecture note (What I learned is on page 24)](https://cs229.stanford.edu/main_notes.pdf)) and I attempted to solve a problem that Obesity classification from Kaggle. [Kaggle Link](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/sujithmandala/obesity-classification-dataset/discussion/457689)

I tried to solve it with following procedure.

1. Seperate data with gender because its form is not numerical but categorical. I will establish my model with respect to gender.
2. With other features, make model to predict status of given person from the perspective of obesity with multinomial classfication.

**But I realized that it is not possible directly with multinomial classification from CS229.**

Because it uses softmax and linear combination. if I suppose that we can solve it only with BMI.

Then we can cluster the distribution of BMI as "too low / low / high / very high" If the BMI is too low, then the status of given person would be "underweight" and if it is low, then it would be "Normal Weight" and so on.

But only with multinomial classification, the model couldn't be established. Because, let the parameters 'p_under', 'p_normal', 'p_over', 'p_obese' are coefficient on BMI. And we know that the value p_under *[BMI] couldn't be the highest value among p*[BMI] set only when given person is underweight and p_normal * [BMI] couldn't be the highest only when given person is normal weighted, and so on.

So my model has failed.

I think this classification problem is very simple and basic problem, so I also think it should be solved with this multinomial(multiclass) classification model. How can I refine my model with it?

Comment: Sorry I was idiot, I completely had forgetten the intercept term.